# Notice: Undefined offset: 2

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to php and I have done an example in php book. In there I got below `notice`. How to prevent this notice ?

```
<?php
require_once('AddingMachine.php');
$arrayofnumbers = array(100,200);
$objectname = new AddingMachine();
$objectname->addNumbers($arrayofnumbers);
?>
```

and

```
<?php
Class AddingMachine
{
private $total = 0;
function addNumbers(array $numbers)
{{
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($numbers);$i++)
{
    $this->total = $this->total + $numbers[$i];
}
   echo $this->total;
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your loop from

```
for($i=0; $i <= sizeof($numbers); $i++)
```

to

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($numbers); $i++)
```

Also preferable to use `count`.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($numbers); $i++)
```

Comment: using sizeof or count inside the forloop is a massive performance hit. Better to define the number into a variable and plug it into the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `<= sizeof($numbers)` (which is equal to `count($numbers)`. It will give you the total count of array elements, which is always one more than the maximum index, because arrays begin counting at 0.

Simply replace the `<=` with `<` and you'll be fine.